# Multi Column Sorting Using Ember JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

My requirement is to sort array using Dynamic property names using EmberJS.

What i have done previously for single column sorting is

```
ents = @get('acceptedEntities')  //get the array 
@set('sortAscending', !@get('sortAscending'))
sort_data = ents.sortBy(property_name) //property name is sort order
```

And what i am looking id

```
 ents = @get('acceptedEntities')  
 @set('sortAscending', !@get('sortAscending'))
 sort_data = ents.sortBy([property_name1, property_name2])
```

I tried with the above solution but no luck and i here about computed sort 
and implemented like this

```
model = @get('acceptedEntities')
sortProperties = [property_name, 'entity_sf_account_name']
sort_data = Ember.computed.sort(model, sortProperties)
```

But Sorting is not going properly, Please give me suggestions to do this.

i tried this too

```
sortProperties = ['one:asc', 'two:desc', 'three:asc']

sort_data = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    content: model,
    sortProperties: sortProperties
})
```

the above code works fine for sorting with multiple parameter but when i want sort order its not working properly

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but I would do it like this:

```
sortProperties = ['one:asc', 'two:desc', 'three:asc']

sort_data = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    content: model,
    sortProperties: sortProperties
})
```

Comment: Hey its working fine when i don't use ascending and descending but if i use it for one column its not sorting properly.
sortProperties = [ property_name, 'entity_sf_account_name:asc', 'portfolio_name:asc']

Comment: I would assume that's just a quirk (bug) of how the `SortableMixin` works. I would just always ensure there's an order on each property.

Comment: How can i do string interpolation for that property in ruby it would be like "#{property_name}:asc". Is it possible in Ember or script?

Comment: It is possible with [ES6 Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). If you're using a later version of Ember-CLI, Babel is enabled by default so you should should be able to do this: `\`${propertyName}:asc\``